Salesforce validation rule to restrict picklist values
I am new to salesforce and I am trying to create a validation rule to restrict picklist values on a field to less than or equal to 5. The value are text
did some research but nothing so far. The picklist values are plain text.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Cast from picklist type (which "likes" ISPICKVAL, INCLUDES etc functions and gets fussy about almost anything else) to text, then from text to number?
Error condition VALUE(TEXT(MyPicklist__c)) > 5 should be enough?

Also you can use the LEN function and validate LEN(TEXT(MyPicklist__c))>5 show the error message Picklist value must be 5 characters.
